# "unrecognized selector sent to instance" on my InGame class

Tags: objective-c, unrecognized-selector

My first question on here, and also my first app:

I keep getting the following message. I'm creating a quiz app, with different categories. Whenever I click on a category, it returns this:

```
    2014-03-21 16:40:20.810 US Government and Politics Quiz[35847:60b] -[InGame Category4]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10ad530d0
    2014-03-21 16:40:20.812 US Government and Politics Quiz[35847:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[InGame Category4]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10ad530d0'
```

And here is my code:

**Categories.m**

```
 (IBAction)Button1:(id)sender{
[Category1 setTitle:@"Political Parties" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
Category1SelectedNumber = 1;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:Category1SelectedNumber forKey:@"CategorySaved"];

}

-(IBAction)Button2:(id)sender{
[Category2 setTitle:@"Pressure Groups" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
Category2SelectedNumber = 2;
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:Category2SelectedNumber forKey:@"CategorySaved"];
}
```

**InGame.m**

```
-(void)loadCategory1{
if (@"CategorySaved" == 1){
switch (QuestionSelected) {
    case 0:
        QuestionText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"What is the general Republican stance on abortion?"];
        [Answer1 setTitle:@"Pro-abortion" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer2 setTitle:@"No stance at all" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer3 setTitle:@"Pro-life" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer4 setTitle:@"Mixture of both" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        Answer3Correct = YES;
        break;

    case 1:
        QuestionText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"What is the general Democrat stance on gay rights?"];
        [Answer1 setTitle:@"Marriage should be between a man and woman" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer2 setTitle:@"Mixture of both" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer3 setTitle:@"No stance at all" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer4 setTitle:@"Marriage should be legal for all couples" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        Answer4Correct = YES;
        break;
}
}}


-(void)loadCategory2{
if (@"CategorySaved" == 2) {
switch (QuestionSelected) {
    case 0:
        QuestionText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Which of these is NOT an ideological pressure group?"];
        [Answer1 setTitle:@"American Conservative Union" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer2 setTitle:@"People for the American Way" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer3 setTitle:@"National Farmers Union" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer4 setTitle:@"American Civil Liberties Union (ACLU)" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        Answer3Correct = YES;
        break;

    case 1:
        QuestionText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Which of the following is not a constitutional requirement to be President?"];
        [Answer1 setTitle:@"Be at least 35 years old" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer2 setTitle:@"Be married to an American" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer3 setTitle:@"Be born in the USA" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [Answer4 setTitle:@"Be a resident in the USA for at least 14 years" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        Answer2Correct = YES;
        break;
}
}}
```

Hopefully that's all that's needed to resolve my issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the class `InGame` implement the instance method `category4`?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem but please completely redo this code. Put the text for the questions and answers in a plist file or database. It's horrible to hardcode all of this text in your app and use giant switch statements. You should be able to handle any number of categories and questions without adding a single line of code to your app.

Comment: And don't ignore compiler warnings. Your code should compile clean. There is no way that your `if` statements comparing an `NSString` literal to an integer constant is valid. I strongly urge you to stop your app development for a moment and find a good tutorial on the Objective-C programming language. Learn the basics now and save a ton of time down the road.

Answer (score 0):

You need to share your "in-game" code because somewhere it is trying to call the `Category4` message on an object of type `InGame`, which doesn't have that method defined. The exception basically says, "hey this object (InGame), doesn't have a method called "Category4".

You need to *at the very least* ensure that there is such a method on the `InGame` class.

You may still have other memory issues that are causing this exception. In which case, you'll need to share more code.

Answer (score 0):

I see `loadCategory1` and `loadCategory2` but no `Category4` selector which is what your `InGame` instance is trying to call; and since it cannot find it (hence *Unknown* selector) it will crash.

Comment: This is not a safe assumption because we can't see all the OP's code.

Comment: The fact is that his `InGame` class doesn't implement a `Category4` selector, or the crash wouldn't happen. I don't see where the assumption is.

Comment: You're assuming you see all of the OPs code. You're also assuming that `loadCategoryX` is some how related to the `Category` property/method. From the code we can see those load methods don't do anything with Category.

Comment: You're assuming we don't see all of OP's code, what's the difference? I've stated a fact relative to what I was provided with. In this case it is safe for me, not him. It makes more sense to add a comment under the question asking if this is the full code, if not, then your comment under my answer would make complete sense and I would happily revise it.